# Getting error in Ajax form from controller in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am updating some features in a site which is made in asp.NET MVC.
I am trying to show an alert when it successfully saves data or when it has some error while saving. My code is something like this:

---------Controller  -----

```
 public JsonResult Insert(string post)
        {
            var posted = Functions.SharePost(post)
            if (posted == true)
            {
                return Json(new { message = "true" });
            }
            return Json(new { message = posted});
        }
```

---- View code --------

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Insert", "WebsitePosting", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",  OnComplete = "CheckError(error);" }))
{
  @Html.TextArea("post", new { data_val_required = "The field is required.", data_val = "true", style = "width:800px" })
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="k-button" />
}
```

----- Script ----

```
<script>
function CheckError(error)
{
   if(error == "true"){alert("success");}
   else{alert("faild");}
 }
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post your error?

Comment: In your java script code you are showing "success message" when error == true. Please verify this once.

Comment: `error` will be an object that either contains a property `message` or a property `success`. You need to check those properties

Comment: @jinesh jain Oh Sorry i write it by mistake , let me update the question ,, actually the controller is returning true

Comment: Change your code to this >> if(error.message == "your post has been shared"){alert("success");}

Comment: @JineshJain no its not working ..

Comment: try to change from OnComplete = "CheckError(error); to `OnSuccess = "CheckError"`

Answer (score 1):

### Update

With your new edits, it should be

```
if (error.message == "true") { alert('success'); }
```

### End update

Error is an object.  Use

```
if (error) {alert('error');}
```

or with jquery

```
if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(error)) { alert('error'); }
```

Your script...

```
<script>
function CheckError(error)
{
   if(error){alert("success");}
   else{alert("faild");}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Dear i try it but not working ,, if you want to ask any other thing i can tell you ..

Comment: updated my answer, use error.message now, did not see you changed your question code.  You should not change your question code unless it was incorrect when you put it up there so people who come along later can see the original question in its entirety.